# I dont want to update but do addition on the current value

Tags: java, android, sqlite, sql-update

This method at the moment just overwrites the current value with the chosen value. Im trying to just add on to the current number already in the credits column. What do I need to add/change to this code to achieve this? I've been looking through a lot of questions but can't figure it out.

```
    public void upDateUser(int money) 
    {
        String selectQuery = "SELECT " + KEY_CREDITS + " from " + 
                         DATABASE_TABLE + " where " + KEY_ROWID + " = " + 0;
        Cursor c = ourDatabase.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        int oldMoney = 0;
        if (c.moveToFirst()) 
        {         
             oldMoney = oldMoney + Integer.parseInt(c.getString(4));
        }
        ContentValues cvUpdate = new ContentValues();
        cvUpdate.put(KEY_CREDITS, (oldMoney + money));
        ourDatabase.update(DATABASE_TABLE, cvUpdate, null, null);
    }
```

Comment: Quick questions: 1. What is `KEY_CREDITS`? Is it a single column name, or is a comma-separated list of columns names? 2. is `KEY_ROWID` autoincremented?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding on to the current value SQLite](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23047462/adding-on-to-the-current-value-sqlite)